# Unpublishing the already filled forms

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

suppose if the designer is unpublishing/making changes to an already submitted form, will the older forms become invalid? whether client can see the older application he/she submitted?

Answer (score 2):

In formsflow.ai Applications tab is a way to monitor all the forms submissions
related data. So even on unpublishing a form designer, as of v4.0.3 release of formsflow.ai the application will be visible to the user. This is to ensure none of form submissions through formsflow.ai which is being maintained by application tab is not being deleted and it's previous history remains to any user regardless of any updates.

> suppose if the designer is unpublishing/making changes to an already submitted form

The changes will remain intact as it was before for an already submitted form in the application Form Tab.

[image]